# Adding a google account without gmail on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, google-calendar

I have two google accs with two different calendars. I want to use them both in the calendar app. However when I try to add the second google account, after entering the google acc details it just jumps back to the calendar settings. Are multiple google accs supported for the iPhone? I can do it with no problems on my mac.

iPhone 6, 10.2

[EDIT]

The problem actually seems to be with the fact that the google account I wanted to add didn't have a gmail address associated with it. So for the purposes of the calendar what I did was adding CalDAV account instead.

[image]

I'll leave this open as a differently formulated question in case someone wants to elaborate on why it's impossible to add a google acc without gmail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is supported. This is what it looks like under settings -> calendar:

[image]

Try adding the account as a mail account and then turning off mail and turning on calendars. This is what it looks like in the calendars app:

[image]

Comment: NoahL's answer works for Contacts as well, using the CardDAV option.

Answer (score 1):

CalDAV (located under the "Other" account option) is possible, but if you have 2FAC enabled, it's not going to work out of the box. You'll have to create a special application specific password and use that password instead of your regular google password in order to get it to work.